# How to import packages in VSCode for python?

Tags: python, import, project

Basically title, I want to have an structure like this:

Project

```
Folders
```

functions.py

I want the code within folders to import functions.py so that I can run those, but despite trying many things I am not managing to make it work, which should be relatively simple.

What I have tried is this: https://imgur.com/a/awvRkkz

I would expect to be able to obtain the correct result but I don't when I run it through VSCode.

One funny thing is that if I run it through the terminal using "python -m mypackaged.test_0", I get the same error unless I have functions.py defined in the parent folder.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)